# Non-editable text box updated in real time from a wxSlider in wxPython

Tags: python, textbox, wxpython, wxtextctrl

I want to create a non-editable text box with no cursor in wxPython. I want it to get updated in real time depending on the values from the wxSlider.

The box will basically have a quadratic equation whose coefficients should change depending on the value of the slider.

**For example** , what I want is very similar to this functionality in LabView -

[image]

Whenever you change the coefficients in the Numerator and Denominator *spin control* (instead of *spin control* I will have a *slider*) it automatically changes in the transfer function textbox.

So what I want to know is:

1. How to create such a text box?
2. How to display a fraction like one in the picture in the text box?
3. How to update the coefficients of the equation in the text box in real time based on changes done by a slider ( or spin control as shown in figure)

Comment: See update: Use matplotlib to render math text if you can accept this dependency (it is a great plot library) or try to generate "math text ASCII art", see [this site](http://ascii.gallery/matheq) as an example, see update.

Comment: @nepix32: Thanks. I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but Chaco has this exact functionality out of the box so I would check it out. They call it their "traits editor" - http://docs.enthought.com/chaco/user_manual/annotated_examples.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: You made it clear that you want to render a formula, sort of. If you only use the inverted quadratic equation you could hack together some "ASCII art". But you will probably want to have something to render math text. As your program involves plots also you may want to incorporate matplotlib. In that case you can use its functionality to render math text (it uses a subset of LaTeX syntax which is builtin without actually requiring TeX). See [this example on the mpl site](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/mathtext_wx.html), especially the `MathTextParser`. And you would use a `wx.StaticBitmap` to display the math text.

What you are searching for should be the [`wx.StaticText`](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/StaticText.html). You would update it with [`SetLabel()`](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Control.html#Control.SetLabel) (method common to ancestor `wx.Control`).

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it working. That link to the mpl site was of great help.

Comment: Though I was able to implement it, I am having some rendering issues. Please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269509/implementaion-of-particular-cases-in-a-mathtext-to-wxbitmap-function)